# Can I install SharePoint SP2 without installing SP1 in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, upgrade, cumulative-update, service-pack

I have SharePoint Server 2010 (Standard edition). However I do not have any SP1 installed in the server. But now I want to use service pack 2 and cumulative updates.

So my question is :

Can I install SP2 directly into my Server without having to install SP1? or What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Service Pack 2 contains all Cummulative Updates and Hot fixes before it.. including SP1

[Install SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 2 the right way](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/install-sharepoint-2010-service-pack-2-the-right-way.html)

[SharePoint Server 2010 Service Pack 2 has been released (Updated July 31st, 2013)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/07/23/sharepoint-server-2010-service-pack-2-has-been-released.aspx)