# How to create setup for Sharepoint 2010 web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, powershell, setup

I have patch 1 until 3. To do the installation for each solution package may take a long time which is it is needed a long step.

So, is there any solution or tools that I can simplify the installation for sharepoint portal to make it as installer? Thanks.

Comment: What patches are you trying to install?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maria,

Cumulative updates contain the previous updates, and Service Packs contain all the previous cumulative updates + previous Service Packs

So you don't need to install every Service Pack and Cumulative update..

Please refer to the following:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224

You should install SP2 as that's the latest Service Pack, and than additionally you can install the December 2013 CU..

Following questions should help too:
[Can I install SharePoint SP2 without installing SP1 in Sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78415/can-i-install-sharepoint-sp2-without-installing-sp1-in-sharepoint-2010/78419#78419)
[How to install CU in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89359/how-to-install-cu-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what i meant is I want to create like setup (.exe) for the sharepoint web application. Is it possible to do that?